# Ajax long polling with curl command

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, spring, curl

I have my files on my localhost and I am trying to make a HTTP long polling request to my web server which is hosted in localhost:7305. Since the browser makes the call with port 80, I get the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. No "Access Control Allow Origin" header is present on the request resource.
```

So I designed a php code with curl to make the call:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:7555/test?list=0");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 7555);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

 $out = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

 echo $out;

 ?>
```

And in my JavaScript this is how I make the ajax long polling request:

```
 function longpoll(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/bypass.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(m) {
           //update some html element with the response
        },
        error: function(e){
           //Error report
        },
        complete: longpoll
        });
 }
```

Its supposed to return a list of strings, but I am getting the error

```
 GET http://localhost/bypass.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
 f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send
 f.extend.ajax
 longpoll
```

I am not sure whats causing this? could it be since ajax is making async call? The web server is in spring and returns a DeferredResult object. Any help is appreciated

Comment: 500 errors are almost always caused by server-side code. you need to now debug the server-side code to see why it returned 500.

Comment: Why are you using php to request from your local webserver when you could instead just properly implement CORS and skip the middleman request?

Comment: @KevinB If I put my javascript code in tomcat and run in the same port as the service, it does not give any issues, it works as needed. So i don't see any server-side issue

Comment: @KevinB I am not sure how to implement the CORS? How could I do this? Any example, help is appreciated

Comment: Depends on the language being used by the webserver. if you searched CORS with that specific language, you'll get plenty of examples.

Comment: @KevinB Its written in Java/Spring. I followed this example https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ and added a class to my server to allow cors but still doesnt work. Should I make any changes to the jquery ajax call?

Comment: nope, the client-side code is fine.

Comment: How long is your longpoll interval?

Comment: I don't set an interval.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. If there's no interval it isn't a long poll. The interval would be defined by Java/spring code.

Comment: @KevinB actually it seems as though I will not able to set CORS on my server. it all has to be done client side with a curl script? Anyway I could do this?

Comment: if you went with cors, you wouldn't need curl, that was the point

Comment: Yah I understand. I can't set CORS permission on the server (its off limits) so I need to be able to do it in the client side. Therefore, I thought the way to do it would be through a curl since I need to do everything on the client side

Comment: yes, curl will be the only option in that case

Comment: so now you need to figure out which of the two servers is giving 500

Comment: I dont think its an issue with the server because if I run my javascript on tomcat and the same port as the server, then it does not give the issue

Comment: it's a 500 error. that by definition is an "internal server error". the client cannot generate that error.

Comment: The purpose of my question before about the interval length was to see if you could possibly be running into a timeout, due to you setting the timeout in curl to 10 seconds. Normally longpolling uses an interval of 30 seconds or more.